# How to add bootstrap table row using same style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I want to add a new table row using jquery. But in my case the style is different. How to solve this problem? Here I have added some screenshot of my code and view. Those are helpful to understand my problem.

HTML portion:

```
<div id="table_show" style="display: none" class="section table-responsive">
      <h2><center>Table View</center></h2>
        <table id="triple_table" width="100%"class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Predicate</th>
            <th>Object</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="info">
              <td class="col-sm-4">Danger</td>
              <td class="col-sm-4">Moe</td>
              <td class="col-sm-4">mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Jquery portion:

```
 var serialized_data='';
   $.each(response_data,function(key, value){
          serialized_data += key + " : " + value +"\n";
          if(key=='id'){
            $("#triple_table").append("<tr>"+"</tr>");
          }
          if(key!=='id'){
          $("#triple_table").append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
         }
        })
        $('#textareashow').append(serialized_data);
```

[My View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zMhf.png)

Comment: Please do not post image of your code, post your code. In that way is easier for us help.

Comment: Do you have more CSS? Where is `serialized_data` defined?

Comment: I forgot to add that line of serializer_data. Now I have edited my code
I added bootstrap CSS. Those are:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'%}">

Comment: Why not just use JQuery's `.clone()` function with a selector like `TBODY TR:first` or `TBODY TR:last`, revise it in memory, and then use `.append()` to append it to the table `TBODY`?

Comment: I have tried to use ".clone()"  but I could not solve it. I am not sure how to use ".clone()" to add a new row.

Answer (score -1):

just add class='info' in append tr

```
$.each(response_data,function(key, value){
          serialized_data += key + " : " + value +"\n";
          if(key=='id'){
            $("#triple_table").append("<tr class='info'>"+"</tr>");
          }
          if(key!=='id'){
          $("#triple_table").append("<td class='info'>" + value + "</td>");
         }
        })
        $('#textareashow').append(serialized_data);
```

Comment: "Adding class=info" also give the same output.